# Filtering IEnumerable<T> dataset with T as Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, lambda

There is a data set as `IEnumerable<T> GridData` which is bound to a data grid. In one scenario data loaded with `T` as `Dictionary<string, object>`. When user apply filter/sort on the grid, I can get those as follows.

```
filters : [{Property: 'abc', Value: 'aaa'}]
sort: [{Property: 'abc'}]
```

on the `Dictionary<string, object>` `Key` represent the `Property` and `Value` represent the `Value`.

I'm stuck with filtering and sorting on `IEnumerable<T> GridData`. Can anyone show me the direction?

Comment: Are you wanting each `Dictionary<T, V>` to be ordered individually, or are you wanting all `Dictionaries` to be sorted as one large data set? Both have unique outcomes.

Comment: I want to order all `Dictionaries` which is stored as `IEnumerable<T> GridData` by selected `Property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a helper function like this

```
    private static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName)?.GetValue(src, null);
    }
```

then filter the GridData like this asuming the filters is an array you need to check against all filters on it.

```
    private static void test<T>(IEnumerable<T> GridData, Dictionary<string, object> filters)
    {

        IEnumerable<T> result = GridData;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> filter in filters.ToList())
        {
            result = result.Where(x =>
                       (x as Dictionary<string, object>).Values.Any(d =>
                         filter.Value.Equals((T)GetPropValue(d, filter.Key))));
        }
    }
```

IF your filters arent a Dictionary, only a List of Tuples<string, object>:

```
    private static void test2<T>(IEnumerable<T> GridData, List<Tuple<string, object>> filters)
    {

        IEnumerable<T> result = GridData;
        foreach (Tuple<string, object> filter in filters.ToList())
        {
            result = result.Where(x =>
                       (x as Dictionary<string, object>).Values.Any(d =>
                         filter.Item2.Equals((T)GetPropValue(d, filter.Item1))));
        }
    }
```

And do the sort using the same aproach

Comment: Thanks for the reply @J.Salas. but `src` parameter on `GetPropValue` method gets a dictionary.  because `T` is `Dictionary<string, object>`. I can not get property by `src.GetType().GetProperty(propName)`

Comment: So do you need to filter for elements in the iEnumerable where any of the elements of the dictionary have a property with the required value? Edited to include that requirement

Comment: yes. that is the requirement. but on your edited answer we cannot take `x.Values` from `T x`.

Comment: Casted the T to dictionary

Comment: Thank you @J.Salas. after some modification I was able to resolve the issue. modified code is `result = result.Where(x =>(x as Dictionary<string, object>).Any(d =>
d.Key.Equals(filter.Property) && d.Value.ToString().Equals(filter.FilterValue)));`